# Mongo: Multiple $inc doesn't work in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to make an $inc to 2 fields, `points` and `sports.wins`:

[image]

When I try to make it through the mongo shell, it works:

```
db.getCollection('userStats').update({
                uid: ObjectId("5ed1bd8313955cbfc60df96f"),
                "sports._id": ObjectId("5ed533c44dcb3efcfe8cb0ec")
            },
                {
                    "$inc": { "sports.$[sports].wins" : 1, "points": 10 },
                },
                { 
                    "arrayFilters": [ 
                            { "sports._id": ObjectId("5ed533c44dcb3efcfe8cb0ec") } 
                    ]
                }
            );
```

However, when I try to make it using bulkWrite (via Mongoose), it only updates the `wins` field:

```
let bulkArray = [];

bulkArray.push({
                updateOne: {
                    filter: {
                        uid: usersWon[i].uid,
                        "sports._id": eventData.reference.sport
                    },
                    update: {
                        "$inc": { 
                            "points": 10,
                            "sports.$[sport].wins": 1,
                        }
                    },
                    arrayFilters: [
                        {
                            "sport._id": sportId
                        }
                    ]
                }
            });
await UserStats.bulkWrite(bulkArray);
```

What am I doing wrong? thanks!

Comment: Is `sportId` an `ObjectId` or just a string? And why are you using different variables ? `eventData.reference.sport` vs `sportId` for the same value

Comment: @thammada.ts It's the same string. It's a ObjectId.

Comment: Just to be sure, have to tried using `eventData.reference.sport` instead of `sportId` ?

Comment: Yes. ```sportId``` is a const ```sportId = eventData.reference.sport;```

Comment: @thammada.ts It seems a bug with mongoose. Trying with the mongo node driver it works.

Comment: Have you tried with the exact _id like `mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5ed533c44dcb3efcfe8cb0ec")` ?

Comment: @thammada.ts Yes. Didn't work. I opened an issue in mongoose repo. Thanks for your time!